# How can I do the content of the slide called "Apartado iv)" smaller to read the code entirely? R studio, beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, rmarkdown

````
---
title: "QUESTION 8 (a)"
author: "Ana Márquez"
date: "17/2/2023"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Dresden"
    colortheme: "beaver"
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
    latex_engine: lualatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tinytex)
library(revealjs)
library(ISLR)
```


# Enunciado

Utilice la función lm() para realizar una regresión lineal simple con "mpg" como respuesta y "horsepower" como predictor. Utilice la función summary() para imprimir los resultados. Comente el resultado. Por ejemplo:



# Apartado i) ¿Existe una relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


```{r}
data(Auto)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
```


##

```{r}
summary(fit)
```

##

Podemos responder a esta pregunta probando la hipótesis $H_0:\beta=0$  $∀_i$. El p valor correspondiente al estadístico F es $7,03198910^{-81}$, lo que indica una clara evidencia de relación entre “mpg” y “horsepower”.


# Apartado ii) ¿Cuál es la relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


Para calcular el error residual relativo a la respuesta utilizamos la media de la respuesta y el RSE.

La media de mpg es $23,4459184$.

El RSE del lm.fit fue de $4,9057569$, lo que indica un porcentaje de error del $20,9237141$%.

También podemos observar que como el R^2 es igual a $0,6059483$, casi el $60,5948258$% de la variabilidad en "mpg" puede explicarse utilizando "horsepower".


# Apartado iii) ¿La relación entre el predictor y la respuesta es positiva o negativa?


Como el coeficiente de "horsepower" es negativo, la relación también lo es. Cuantos más caballos tenga un automóvil, la regresión lineal indica que tendrá menos mpg de eficiencia de combustible.


# Apartado iv) ¿Cuál es la predicción de *mpg* asociada a un "horsepower" de 98? ¿Cuáles son los intervalos de confianza y predicción del 95% asociados?


```{r}
predict(fit, data.frame(horsepower = 98), interval = "confidence")
```


```{r}
predict(fit, data.frame(horsepower = 98), interval = "prediction")
```
````

My question is that:
I want The slide of "Apartado iv)" smaller because the code of "predict..." appears so big and you can´t read it the whole code. The same happens with the code of `{r} summary(fit)` 
It appears so big so you can not read the whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually change the font size by e.g. adding `\footnotesize` to the frame:

````
---
title: "QUESTION 8 (a)"
author: "Ana Márquez"
date: "17/2/2023"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "Dresden"
    colortheme: "beaver"
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
    latex_engine: lualatex
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tinytex)
library(revealjs)
library(ISLR)
```


# Enunciado

Utilice la función lm() para realizar una regresión lineal simple con "mpg" como respuesta y "horsepower" como predictor. Utilice la función summary() para imprimir los resultados. Comente el resultado. Por ejemplo:



# Apartado i) ¿Existe una relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


```{r}
data(Auto)
fit <- lm(mpg ~ horsepower, data = Auto)
```


##

```{r}
summary(fit)
```

##

Podemos responder a esta pregunta probando la hipótesis $H_0:\beta=0$  $∀_i$. El p valor correspondiente al estadístico F es $7,03198910^{-81}$, lo que indica una clara evidencia de relación entre “mpg” y “horsepower”.


# Apartado ii) ¿Cuál es la relación entre el predictor y la respuesta?


Para calcular el error residual relativo a la respuesta utilizamos la media de la respuesta y el RSE.

La media de mpg es $23,4459184$.

El RSE del lm.fit fue de $4,9057569$, lo que indica un porcentaje de error del $20,9237141$%.

También podemos observar que como el R^2 es igual a $0,6059483$, casi el $60,5948258$% de la variabilidad en "mpg" puede explicarse utilizando "horsepower".


# Apartado iii) ¿La relación entre el predictor y la respuesta es positiva o negativa?


Como el coeficiente de "horsepower" es negativo, la relación también lo es. Cuantos más caballos tenga un automóvil, la regresión lineal indica que tendrá menos mpg de eficiencia de combustible.


# Apartado iv) ¿Cuál es la predicción de *mpg* asociada a un "horsepower" de 98? ¿Cuáles son los intervalos de confianza y predicción del 95% asociados?

\footnotesize

```{r}
predict(fit, data.frame(horsepower = 98), interval = "confidence")
```


```{r}
predict(fit, data.frame(horsepower = 98), interval = "prediction")
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank thank you so much!! It helps me a lot.

Comment: @Ana You're welcome!